# Accessing results in DAO.RecordSet

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using this SQL query

```
SELECT TOP 11 StockPrices.Close FROM StockPrices WHERE StockPrices.Date >=#2009-03-23# AND StockPrices.ID=1 ORDER by StockPrices.Date;
```

in VBA to fetch and store the data and keeping in a recordset

```
SQLQuery = "SELECT TOP 11 StockPrices.Close FROM StockPrices WHERE StockPrices.Date >=#" & tempDate & "# AND StockPrices.ID=" & tempId & " ORDER by StockPrices.Date;"
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(SQLQuery)
Pd = rst2.Fields(0)
Pd1 = rst2.Fields(1)
Pd5 = rst2.Fields(5)
Pd11 = rst2.Fields(10)
rst2.Close
```

While Pd is being queried perfectly, but I am not able to access the rest of the data. As I understand, there is only one Field here, i.e the Close, which is coming up as Fields(0), I want to access the other data in the same field..

Let me give you an example, the queried result of the above SQL query is like this

```
3940
2544
5544
5633
1257
9855
3267
3141
2731
6931
```

SO I want the first, the second, the fifth and the tenth data in the listm which should be stored in Pd, Pd1,Pd5 and Pd11.

Any help, in how to do this?

Soham

Comment: What are you doint with the variables `pd`, `pd`, etc.? It looks to me like you are populating controls via a recordset, when instead you should be using a form and assigning the SQL SELECT as its Recordsource.

Comment: Simply using them to calculate another three variables in VBA

Comment: Why can't you just do the calculation directly? Frankly, the whole thing looks incoherent to me -- I can't figure out why you'd want to be selecting only some of the values from your TOP 11 list. It looks like an arbitrary choice, particularly if you're doing some kind of calculations on those numbers. Also, are you accounting for the fact that TOP N in Jet/ACE SQL returns ties, so it might return 12 or more records?

Comment: @David, Because I just want the next 11 days closing prices

Comment: So, why not just load the records in a form? Why use a recordset at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Pd1 = rst2.Fields(1)` you are accessing the second column of the current row.
If you want to access the second row, you need to use `rst2.MoveNext`.
Below code would save all results to the `results()` array.
You could access the fifth result with `results(4)`.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim results(11) as Integer
i = 0
Do while Not rst2.EOF
    results(i) = rs2.fields(0)
    i = i + 1
    rst2.MoveNext
Loop
```

To move a number of steps you can use `rst2.Move 4` i.e. for moving four steps.
The best way would be to only get the rows you need (1,5 and 11).

Comment: So, to go to the 5 row, I have to add Movenext 4 times? What a terrible way

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with Access, but did you try storing the output into an Array and then referencing to the array values?

Cheers,
Visakh